# how to get data copied to sheet if condition met and if not, append data to last row? VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, find, range

Data sheet (Data Source) has the data in the format below:

```
Case ID      Contact     Email           Address
999          Jim         jim@jim.com     (blank)
998          (blank)     (blank)         (blank)
```

Issues sheet (Destination) has a list of Case ID's with Issue 1 alreaedy filled out. There is an Issues list (Issues 2 onwards) in the format below + desired output:

```
Case ID      Issue 1        Issue 2      Issue 3
999                                      address
998          contact        email        address
```

**GOAL**: Since some Case ID's are already present in Issues, the goal is to get the macro to scan through Data sheet and if the Case ID is *FOUND*,

- check to see if Issue 2 field is blank. If it is, get the column heading and paste into the same row where the Case ID is located in Issues.
- if the Case ID is *NOT FOUND*, then append the Case ID to the last row of Issues, Column A and also add the column heading to the Issue 2 column in the same row.

The goal is to highlight issues within the Data sheet with multiple conditions and paste them into Issues sheet. In this case, with the code below, the IF statement searches for cells that have Interior.ColorIndex = 2 on the Data sheet.

PROBLEM: my current code does not cycle through correctly and append CASE ID's not found to the last row of Sheet 1. Also, I'm not confident my counters are setup correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub IssuesData()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim lastrow2 As Long
Dim lastrow3 As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim wb As Workbook

lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastrow3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Issues").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For j = 2 To lastrow3
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 10).Interior.ColorIndex = 2 Then
            If Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 3) = Sheets("Issues").Cells(j, 1) Then

            Sheets("Issues").Cells(j, "D") = Sheets("Data").Cells(1, 10)

            End If
        j = j + 1


            Else
                If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 10).Interior.ColorIndex = 2 Then
                lastrow2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Issues").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 3).Copy
                Sheets("Issues").Range("A" & lastrow2 + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                Sheets("Data").Cells(1, 10).Copy
                Sheets("Issues").Range("D" & lastrow2 + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                End If
            End If

    Next i
Next j

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working - hope it helps someone!

```
Sub ReadC1LegalContact()

Dim frng As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim pasteRow As Long



    With ThisWorkbook

        lastrow = Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To lastrow

            If Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 60).Interior.ColorIndex = 1 Then
                Set frng = Sheets("Issues").Range("A:A").Find(Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 3), , xlValues, xlWhole)

                If Not frng Is Nothing Then
                    If .Sheets("Issues").Cells(frng.Row, "B") = "" Then
                       .Sheets("Issues").Cells(frng.Row, "B") = .Sheets("Data").Cells(1, 60)
                    End If
                Else
                    pasteRow = .Sheets("Issues").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    .Sheets("Issues").Range("A" & pasteRow) = .Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 3)
                    .Sheets("Issues").Range("B" & pasteRow) = .Sheets("Data").Cells(1, 60)
                End If
            End If

        Next i

    End With
End Sub
```